# MYSQL auto-generated Query syntax error

Tags: mysql

Can anyone tell me what is wrong in syntax below?its an auto-generated one from MYSQL workbench,so I doubt there is anything wrong with syntax

```
ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`postcommit_si_flags_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `software_ima' at line 5
SQL Statement:
CREATE TABLE `aci_dev`.`postcommit_si_flags` (
  `postcommit_si_flags_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `software_image_id` INT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  `bypass_testcase_failure` TINYINT NOT NULL,
  `base_meta`  NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`postcommit_si_flags_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `software_image_id_UNIQUE` (`software_image_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `software_image_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`software_image_id`)
    REFERENCES `aci_dev`.`software_images` (`software_image_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base_meta have not type

```
 `base_meta`  NOT NULL,
```

should be eg:

```
 `base_meta` int  NOT NULL,
```